# Why isn't 'bundler/setup' including any of the gems in my Gemfile?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'd like to use `bundler/setup` to include all of my listed gems but I'm not
succeeding. In `go.rb` I have

```
require 'rubygems'                                                                                                
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('Gemfile', __FILE__)                                                   
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

which fails to require `httparty` as I thought it would:

```
$ bundle exec ruby go.rb                                                                                          
go.rb:5:in `<main>': uninitialized constant HTTParty (NameError)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

---

I've created a small project for this question, [here](https://github.com/blt/bundler_question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand `'bundler/setup'` it only manages the require path (removes the default contents and adds paths for gems that are defined in `Gemfile.lock`). If you don't require the libraries in question, their contents won't be available.

Comment: @troutwine you can do `Bundler.require(:default)` after `require 'bundler/setup'` to require all the gems in the default group (you can also specify other groups). See [the docs](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html#setting-up-your-application-to-use-bundler) for more info

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem in your particular case is the following snippet:

```
File.expand_path('Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

If I run this from a file called `/foo/bin/somescript`, what the above code expands to is `/foo/bin/somescript/Gemfile`.  Presumably what you actually want is `/foo/bin/Gemfile`, which you can get with:

```
File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __FILE__)
```

So, repeating your original code with the correction:

```
require 'rubygems'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

This seems to work for me, to have files in my `~/bin` directory have access to libraries I've installed by running `bundle install` within that directory, as specified by the `Gemfile` therein.